# Is Google's new URL shortener service g.co already usable?

Tags: google, url-shortening

Some time ago, Google acquired the domain g.co as an URL shortener exclusively for its own services (e.g. [Tech Crunch](http://techcrunch.com/2011/07/18/google-buys-g-co-to-create-an-official-url-shortcut-for-google-products/)).

So far, I haven't seen it in use anywhere, and it would be very useful for long links such as those from the [public data explorer](http://www.google.com/publicdata/).

None of the news reports I read mentioned when it could be used.

Can I already use it or are they still working on it? Is there a release date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is. See the screenshot below. I just used it moments ago (7th of September 2011).

[image]

Answer (score 6):

According to the [official Google blog](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2011/07/gco-official-url-shortcut-for-google.html), [g.co](http://g.co/) **sends you only to webpages that are owned by Google**, and **only Google can create [g.co](http://g.co/) shortcuts**.

When you open [g.co](http://g.co/) web page, it says:

> You’ve arrived at this page because you typed or linked to “g.co”,
>   Google’s official URL shortcut just for Google websites.
>
> Whenever you see a short “g.co” link, you can trust that it will
>   always take you to a Google product or service.
>
> We also have a public URL shortener at [goo.gl](http://goo.gl). You can use this
>   to shorten up URLs across the web.

Note: Google announced g.co on 18/7/2011.

Comment: It's Google's business to create content based on their user's input (search strings, location coordinates, etc.). As far as I understand it, g.co will only be able to be used from inside a Google application (e.g. the "Link" link in Google Maps will produce a short g.co link instead of today's mess). But so far I've seen nothing like this.

Comment: @Legate - There's a Maps Lab, which currently uses goo.gl/maps/ to produce a shortened URL.

Comment: @Joel H I see only seven Maps Labs at the moment and none of them has to do with URL shortening.

Comment: It may have broke with the recent UI changes.